Как настроить опцию ввода предложения в переменную в Телеграм боте?
Настраиваю функцию переводчик. Мне нужно чтобы этот бот запрашивал, какое предложение нужно перевести и перевел это предложение. Проблема в том, что у меня получилось только задать в переменную само предложение и бот переводит это предложение. но не знаю как настроить так чтоб пользователь с телеграмма вводил предложение.
Мой код здесь:
import telebot
from telebot import types
from translate import Translator
TOKEN='...'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)
ru_letters = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя"
en_letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(message):
    message_user = f"Привет, <b>{message.from_user.first_name.title()}</b>! Я тестовый бот.\n" \
                   f"<b>Выбери программу, которую ты хочешь выполнить:</b>\n" \
                   f"1. Чем полезен данный бот\n" \
                   f"2. Функционал бота(что может данный бот)\n" \
                   f"3. Для тех кто хочет поддержать нас и наш проект"
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton(text="Чем полезен бот ?")
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton(text="Функции бота")
    item3 = types.KeyboardButton(text="Поддержать проект")
    markup.add(item1, item2, item3)
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, message_user, reply_markup=markup, parse_mode='html')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, impact_KEYBORD_bot)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, fuctional_KEYBORD_bot)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, donat_user_bot)
def impact_KEYBORD_bot(message):
    if message.text == "Чем полезен бот ?":
        message_user = "Этот бот много чем будет полезен для вас. Ознакомьтесь с функционалом бота чтобы понять это." \
                       " В этого бота со временем мы будем внедрять новые фичи и полезные функции. Чтобы узнавать о новых фишках бота, слидите за нашим Telegramm каналом"
        key = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Мое портфолио', url="https://dato138it.ru")
        key.add(button)
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, message_user, reply_markup=key, parse_mode='html')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, fuctional_KEYBORD_bot)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, donat_user_bot)
def fuctional_KEYBORD_bot(message):
    if message.text == 'Функции бота':
        message_user = "<b>Добро пожаловать главное меню бота</b>\n\n" \
                       "В скором будущем мы будем добавлять сюда новые функции!"
        key = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        button0 = types.KeyboardButton("Переводчик")
        button1 = types.KeyboardButton("Словарь")
        key.add(button0, button1)
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, message_user, reply_markup=key, parse_mode='html')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, impact_KEYBORD_bot)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, donat_user_bot)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, translate_message)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, dictionary_message)
def donat_user_bot(message):
    if message.text == "Поддержать проект":
        message_users = f"<b>Приветствую  уважаемый {message.from_user.first_name.title()}</b>, вы перешли в отдел поддержки нашего проекта \n\n" \
                        f"Мы будем благодарны любой поддержки от вас. И также благодарим, что вы пользуетесь нашим ботом - это главная ваша поддержка для нас!\n\n" \
                        f"Мы принимаем материальную поддержку на:\n" \
                        f"<b>1. Donationalerts</b>\n" \
                        f"<b>2. PAYEER</b>\nномер счёта для пополнения: P1091200672\n" \
                        f"<b>3. QIWI</b>\n" \
                        f"<b>4. Тинькофф банк</b>"
        key = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        button0 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Donationalerts", url="https://www.donationalerts.com/r/tgbot_v")
        button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="PAYEER", url="https://payeer.com/ru/account/send/")
        button2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="QIWI", url="https://my.qiwi.com/VLADYSLAV-DTJ4Y_MwOA")
        button3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Тинькофф банк", url="https://www.tinkoff.ru/cf/35TWsWpG8Fe")
        key.add(button0, button1, button2, button3)
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, message_users, reply_markup=key, parse_mode='html')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, impact_KEYBORD_bot)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, fuctional_KEYBORD_bot)
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def translate_message(message):
    if message.text == 'Переводчик':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Напишите сообщения а я переведу его')
        text = "Hello!"
        if text[0].lower() in ru_letters:
            translator = Translator(from_lang="russian", to_lang="english")
        elif text[0].lower() in en_letters:
            translator = Translator(from_lang="english", to_lang="russian")
        translated_text = translator.translate(text)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, translated_text)
def dictionary_message(message):
    if message.text == 'Словарь':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'list | term')
        #text = message.text
        #bot.send_message("TEST")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)

Вот сам результат этого запроса:
-Добро пожаловать главное меню бота
В скором будущем мы будем добавлять сюда новые функции!
-Переводчик
-Напишите сообщения а я переведу его
-Здравствуйте!

То есть в первом диалоге он запрашивает у пользователя какие функции ему выбрать, он выбирает Переводчик, потом запрашивает сообщение которое нужно перевести, и он автоматически переводит его, а пользователь то ничего не написал.
Пробовал менять функцию таким образом:
def translate_message(message):
    if message.text == 'Переводчик':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Напишите сообщения а я переведу его')
        text = str(message.chat.id)
        if text[0].lower() in ru_letters:
            translator = Translator(from_lang="russian", to_lang="english")
            translated_text = translator.translate(text)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, translated_text)
        elif text[0].lower() in en_letters:
            translator = Translator(from_lang="english", to_lang="russian")
            translated_text = translator.translate(text)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, translated_text)

В ответ ничего не выдает. что я делаю не так?

Все просто, сначала вам нужно разбить функцию translate_message на две части, первая будет обрабатывать сообщение "Переводчик", а вторая будет получать следующее сообщение и переводить его.
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def translate_message(message):
    if message.text == 'Переводчик':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Напишите сообщения а я переведу его')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, translate_message_step_2)
def translate_message_step_2(message):
   text = message.text
   if text[0].lower() in ru_letters:
        translator = Translator(from_lang="russian", to_lang="english")
   elif text[0].lower() in en_letters:
        translator = Translator(from_lang="english", to_lang="russian")
   translated_text = translator.translate(text)
   bot.send_message(message.chat.id, translated_text)

В таком случае первая функция завершится когда пользователь отправит следующее сообщение и передаст его во вторую функцию

У вас, как минимум, нет обработки сообщения с текстом (кроме кнопки "перевод").
А во-вторых, text = str(message.chat.id) текст - строка с айди пользователя.
Соответственно, нужно добавить обработчик, в котором получить текст соббщения

спрашивал в разные группы, про обработчик, вопрос мой либо удаляют, либо ответа нету, даже в гугле. можешь посоветовать как пишется обработчик? я новичок в этом деле

@DatoDato я сейчас не занимаюсь ботами в ТГ, просто в вашем коде видно нарушение логики. Обработчик у вас сделан на функцию translate_message, например. Туда попадает весь текст, что отправляют боту. А дальше стоит условие, какой текст обрабатывать. Для начала стоит изучить документацию, на предмет того, можно ли задать if message.text == 'Переводчик': как условие в декораторе, тогда в эту функцию не будет попадать лишний текст, и вы сможете ловить текст дальше.  Сейчас у вас ВЕСЬ текст попадает в эту функцию
